# How to get All test cycle from ZAPI rest call

Tags: jira-zephyr

I am trying to use this API to manage my automation test cases in Jira-Zephyr.

I am trying to get all the test cycle from my project, So as per the ZAPI technical doc I used
http://localhost:8080/jira/rest/zapi/latest/cycle?projectId=10002&versionId=10100
But it is not working, It says that it is a dead link.

I googled for search all the issue from project, So I got the below one
http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=10002
and it is working fine for me.

So as per this link I changed the above link

It is also not working.

How I can Find out all the test cycle present in the project?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me with a local install of Jira + zapi, zephry add-ons

http://localhost:8080/rest/zapi/latest/cycle?projectId={{projectId}}&versionId={{versionId}}

Answer (score 0):

try like this, def clientTestID = new RESTClient("https://XXXXXXXXXX.net/rest/zapi/latest/zql/executeSearch?maxRecords=9999&zqlQuery=cycleId=XXXXX")
This will work for sure if headers are properly defined

Comment: Please check [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Format this.